# How to setup one Redis cluster across multiple Kubernetes cluster

Tags: kubernetes, redis

I have a specific requirement to create kind of a DR and blue green infra for my project that I am building for which I need to setup a single Redis cluster on two separate Kubernetes clusters. How can I do it?

I have gone through various implementations but they all are for single K8s cluster. Please advise. Thanks

Comment: Single redis cluster shared by two k8s clusters? Does the redis cluster have to be on k8s nodes? If so, do the nodes have to be distributed among both k8s clusters?

Comment: Yes on both k8s cluster's nodes and yes have to be distributed among both k8s clusters. I have a specific requirement to create kind of a DR and blue green infra for my project that I am building.